# Angular-CLI. How to register new module in current one?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, module, dependencies

I've generated a modules:

```
$  ng generate module myTestModule
installing module
  create src/app/my-test-module/my-test-module.module.ts

$  ng generate module myTestModule2
installing module
  create src/app/my-test-module2/my-test-module2.module.ts
```

I have usual file describes the main module `app.module.ts`. How could I register module `my-test-module.module.ts` in the `app.module.ts` and `my-test-module2.module.ts` in the `my-test-module.module.ts`?

---

**Some more details to help improve answers**

```
$ ng generate --help

module <name> <options...>
  aliases: m
  --spec (Boolean) Specifies if a spec file is generated.
  --flat (Boolean) Flag to indicate if a dir is created.
  --routing (Boolean) (Default: false) Specifies if a routing module file should be generated.
  --app (String) Specifies app name to use.
    aliases: -a <value>
```

no `-m` or `--module` here like declared on [wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-module)

My angular cli:

```
$ ng -v

@angular/cli: 1.0.1
node: 7.4.0
@angular/common: 4.1.3
@angular/compiler: 4.1.3
@angular/core: 4.1.3
@angular/forms: 4.1.3
@angular/http: 4.1.3
@angular/platform-browser: 4.1.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.3
@angular/router: 4.1.3
@angular/cli: 1.0.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.3
```

---

**Some more details to help improve answers v2**
I've updated `angular-cli` to v1.2.1. I can use alias `-m`

```
module <name> <options...>
  aliases: m
  --spec (Boolean) Specifies if a spec file is generated.
  --flat (Boolean) Flag to indicate if a dir is created.
  --routing (Boolean) (Default: false) Specifies if a routing module file should be generated.
  --app (String) Specifies app name to use.
    aliases: -a <value>
  --module (String) Specifies where the module should be imported.
    aliases: -m <value>
```

So I try

```
$ ng g m MyTestModuleModule34 -m AppModule

installing module
Specified module does not exist
```

But specified module is present in `src/app/app-module.ts`

Comment: By doing what you'd do with *any* module; add it to the relevant `imports`.

Comment: Add `import { TestModuleModule } from test-module.module.ts;` to top of app.ts, add `imports: [ TestModuleModule, ... ]` to `@NgModule`. Also, you might want to consider doing a `ng generate module my-test` since it already appends the module part.

Comment: @Z.Bagley Why should I add `TestModuleModule` into `@NgModule` `imports` block? I expected it should be in `declarations` block.

Comment: Your `imports` section is for importing Modules which have their own `declarations`. An easier way to think of it is that your TestModule will **declare** it's own Components. Your AppModule needs to **import** those declarations.

Comment: Thanks Deborahk for her help. I've found working example! Sharing to all `ng g m MyTestModuleModule37 -m=app.module.ts`. It adds automatically dependency into specified module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate the module, you can use the -m flag and specify the name of the module you want to register it in. The cli will then register the module for you.

Comment: Could you please improve your help? Sorry it's not enough clear for me. I tried `ng generate module MyTestModuleModule3 --m AppModule`, result is `The option '--m' is not registered with the generate command. Run `ng generate --help` for a list of supported options.`

Comment: I've checked some [examples](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-module) it seems I should use exactly `-m` or `--module`. May be I should fix somewhere else? I checked `ng -v` result is `@angular/cli: 1.0.1` and other angular dependencies are `4.1.3`

Comment: Sorry ... my plane was landing and I ran out of time ... will post an example when I can.

Comment: But yes ... as I mentioned in my answer... -m not --m

Comment: I tried `-m`, tried `--m` and `--module` following your point and [wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-module) but result is the same.

Comment: I've added some details into my question that should help you check my `ng` env.

Comment: See where it says "alias m" that means you can use -m.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149057/discussion-between-sergii-and-deborahk).

Comment: Sorry ... I'm on vacation now and don't have a decent computer with me. Hopefully someone else can figure out why the -m does not work for you.

Comment: I've printed solution into chat discussion. Also it is added as comment to my question. Solution is based on your idea. Technical issues are fixed.

Comment: @Sergil You don't need the module suffix when using -m so `ng g module myTest -m app` will create TestModule and register it in AppModule.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why -m isn't working but you can manually import them, it takes a whole 2 seconds.

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MyTestModule
  ]
})
```

**my-test-module.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MyTestModule2 // This should be named MyTest2Module for naming consistancy throughout your app. i.e. all module names should end with the word module. See the Angular Style Guide for more info.
  ]
})
```

On a side note, there is no reason to include Module twice in any of the names. Instead just use `my-test.module.ts` and `my-test-two.module.ts`